# Why is this Mac mini so slow?

Tags: memory, mac-mini, performance, macos

To replace my mid-2011 **iMac** (*12 GB RAM, 2.7 GHz i5, Radeon 512 MB*), whose Radeon Graphics card is slowly passing away, I purchased a mid-2011 **Mac mini** (*10 GB RAM, 2.5 i5, Radeon 256 MB*) with same HD capacity, and carried over my data with **Time Machine**.

After successfully repairing an issue with the Startup Volume in Recovery mode, I am finding the mini to be incredibly slow to do anything.
For example, opening a Finder window takes a good 2 minutes. Even my mom's never-upgraded 2009 iMac is much, much faster with lesser specs.

Since I migrated the data from a (rather fast) iMac, I am ruling out malware or system cache issues. I didn't see anything peculiar in Activity Monitor and Disk Utility says all is okay.

Here is the detail of the [HD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmbCJ.png) and the [RAM installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA1mX.png).

My first suggestion would be that the culprit is the Ram that is installed being from different vendors and capacity, but I am baffled to find out how I could be sure that this is the problem before I open it up in case I have to return it.

**What is possibly making this Mac mini so slow and how can I know for sure?**

Comment: If you suspect the RAM, can't you try moving the RAM from the iMac to the Mini?

Comment: Are they compatible? If they are, yes, I could definitely. Or simply remove either the 8 or the 2Gb ram from the Mini to see if it's less slow without it. But if there was a way to know for sure before opening it, that'd be great...

Comment: The RAM seems to be compatible. See https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.3-mid-2011-specs.html

Comment: See also what https://etrecheck.com report for the Mini

Comment: @lhf Here are EtreCheck reports [one](https://pastebin.com/tecUgXuj) and [two](https://pastebin.com/Vy86ukKi) (I had two versions of Etrecheck). What do you think? Nothing about the incompatible RAM but something weird was detected about the HD...

Comment: I would look deeper into the hard drive issue.  Open Terminal and issue the following command:  `diskutil info disk0 | grep -i SMART`.  If it says "Verified" you're not out of the woods just yet, you'll want to do some more diagnostics.  However, if it says failing, it's time for a new drive.  However, given that it's a 5400RPM 9+ year old spinning drive, why not upgrade it and be done?

Comment: @Allan Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help. The command you suggested returned a "Verified". Not sure what other diagnostics I can run in Terminal. I reached out to the seller and he said there's another 1Tb drive inside the Mac, so I restarted with the ALT key and saw another drive called "Windows", but it doesn't have an operating system [a new challenge in itself] (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399590/how-can-i-install-macos-on-the-second-hard-drive-inside-a-computer). For now I'll try to clone the (one of the) drives better and try to use it!

Comment: Wait...there’s two drives?   Can you post the output of `diskutil list` To your question?  The Windows is probably boot camp which is a popular thing to do...it’s not necessarily another drive.

Comment: Yes. [Here is it](https://imgur.com/a/PkI9Q6z). Although the seller says "The system has 2TB of HDD space on two separate hard drive with 1TB one each" but I am having a hard time verifying that? Could Terminal only see one of them if the other one has Windows installed on it? I did a new copy of my data after I found a Firewire cable and the copy is better this time.

Comment: I also realized doing the Target mode transfer that the HD in the mac mini wasn't a GUID partition and I fixed that.

Comment: The answer was that the partition scheme was wrong and it started behaving normally after changing that.