# How can I install macOS on the second hard drive inside a computer?

Tags: hard-drive

I just bought a 2011 Mac mini which has two hard drives inside. One of the hard drives had a Mac Recovery I was able to transfer my data to with Time Machine, the other one is called "Windows" so I'm assuming it's formatted differently.

[image]

Can I format the Windows drive to install a Mac system on it without opening the computer?

*Edit: After reinstalling twice, I am not sure there is a second hard drive inside the Mac anymore. I updated the question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399765/how-many-hard-drives-are-in-this-mac-mini). I will edit further this question once I understand what is going on inside this machine.*

Comment: This question depends on the answer to Allan's comment below your last question - is it actually 2 drives or just a bootcamp partition? Post the output of `diskutil list` to your question so we can see. As this is a 'new to you' Mac, you ought to start by wiping the entire drive & installing a new clean OS.

Comment: [Here is it](https://imgur.com/a/PkI9Q6z). But the screenshot in my question shows two hard drives, no? The seller says "The system has 2TB of HDD space on two separate hard drive with 1TB one each"

Comment: Posting it into your question as text would have been a lot better than as a picture on an external site - but, no, that does not show two separate drives, it shows one internal 1TB drive & a mounted disk image.

Comment: Comments are limited in characters and I didn't think one could copy the contents of Terminal (how?), sorry. Does this result clarify what the drive named "Windows" is?

Comment: You drag your cursor over text in terminal just the same as any other app, copy, then paste it into your original question. Select that text & hit Ctrl/k which will format it legibly as "code". & no, it gives no hint as to where the Windows partition might be.

Comment: TBH, we're going through this in far more detail than we really need to. What you should do is read Apple's [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) The original owner should have already done the first steps - you hope, except people don't - leaving the last step for you. Complete wipe & reinstall the OS - no need to mess with 'what's this partition' questions at all.

Comment: I understand and agree 100%. Thanks for the input. I guess I am wondering, since I can start with ALT pressed and see the two drives, if I could do something similar to have Recovery mode run on the other drive. Or something I could do to install or transfer data to it. Right now I'm afraid the only option is to either take the machine apart or never use that extra Tb I paid for...

Comment: You don't see "two drives" you see "two partitions". Don't let that mislead you - go through the wipe & reinstall from scratch process & during that you will easily determine how many physical drives are in the machine. Right now, I'd say one - but the evidence is only circumstantial, we don't have a full picture.

Comment: @Tetsujin How would I reinstall from scratch and be able to format both drives? That's what I was trying to do but whenever I have started the computer in Recovery or Target mode, I could only see one drive (onto which I then reinstalled completely my data). Can there be 2 drives but I can only see one of them when in Recovery or Target mode?

Comment: We have yet to see any real evidence one exists.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well I may have to make another question that tries to figure that out, then... And if "Windows" is just a partition of the same drive, why can't I access it or see it in Disk Utility?...

Comment: We are just going round in circles now. Do the complete wipe & reinstall from the Apple web site. See what you end up with. We are working on incomplete information; there is no answer right now, short of opening the Mac & counting the drives.

Comment: [This process](https://www.howtogeek.com/186860/HOW-TO-REINSTALL-OS-X-ON-YOUR-MAC-WIPE-YOUR-DRIVE-AND-CREATE-USB-INSTALLATION-MEDIA/)? I did the first two steps, since I changed the partition scheme of the drive I can access (it was not a GUID partition). Therefore I think it was completely reformatted. Step three results in [this](https://imgur.com/a/x9m9fFr). Restarting with ALT results in [this](https://imgur.com/a/9HHJEG9).

Comment: idk why you are following 3rd party instructions rather than those from Apple as in my earlier link. So far all I can guess is you didn't do it correctly. You still have not provided sufficient information to guess any further.

Comment: Didn't realize your link was meant for me versus what the seller should have done before selling. I looked and the process I followed is the exact same one as [the Apple one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496). Whether I am in recovery mode to erase the drive or count the drives, I only see one drive. Terminal diskutil list [output](https://pastebin.com/w6i7KBdk) while in Recovery mode.

Comment: diskutil still says you have one drive in there, you boot screen says you didn't erase the drive properly.

Comment: The boot screen has changed since I restored the hard drive, but I cannot update the question since it has become "are there two drives?" now. I have [updated the question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399765/how-many-hard-drives-are-in-this-mac-mini), as this one cannot be updated to reflect what I found out by restoring the computer twice. Apologies for the confusion and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You should 1st check if you can read the windows disk. If so, make sure there is nothing on it you want. If you don't care what's on it skip that and go to disk utility. Using disk utility you can erase the windows disk and reformat it in a format you want. Then you can load the Mac System on the disk.

Comment: I cannot read the Windows disk, it seems blank. When I boot from it with the ALT key, I just get a "Missing operating system" message on white over black background... and that's where I'm stuck to even know whether it's a drive or a partition...