# iMac 27 How to restore a SSD made invisible after formatting a fusion drive from APFS to HFS+

Tags: ssd, fusion-drive, hfs+

I bought a used Imac 27 with APFS fusion drive mOdel Identifier iMac15,1 before discovering the previous owner had replaced the original 512 Gb SSD by third party one with an adapter. After formatting the fusion drive back to HFS+ with disk utility, and installing OSX 10.12.6 (Sierra)  with my previous data from my older computer, the SSD became invisible both in disk utility and diskutil (see the first lines of the "disk utility list" command. I have made additional investigations, and determined that booting from a High sierra or above OS the SSD is again visible, and I was able to partition it, make an HFS+ Fusion drive with the HDD or a partition of the HDD, etc all operations appearing normal. However when booting again from Sierra, neither the SDD nor the Fusion drive are visible in diskutil or disk utility. I want to stick to Sierra for a number orf reasons including compatibilty with other older machines.  How could I restore the SSD to become visible and useful again ? Just below are the first lines of the result of the command system_profiler SPSerailATADataType (after upgrading again to OS 10.15.5
system_profiler SPSerialATADataType
SATA/SATA Express:

```
Intel 8 Series Chipset:

  Vendor: Intel
  Product: 8 Series Chipset
  Link Speed: 6 Gigabit
  Negotiated Link Speed: 6 Gigabit
  Physical Interconnect: SATA
  Description: AHCI Version 1.30 Supported

    ST4000DM006-2G5107:

      Capacity: 4 TB (4 000 787 030 016 bytes)
      Model: ST4000DM006-2G5107                      
      Revision: DN04    
      Serial Number: ZC19X1NJ
      Native Command Queuing: Yes
      Queue Depth: 32
      Removable Media: No
      Detachable Drive: No
      BSD Name: disk1
      Rotational Rate: 7200
      Medium Type: Rotational
      Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
      S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
      Volumes:
        EFI:
          Capacity: 209,7 MB (209 715 200 bytes)
          File System: MS-DOS FAT32
          BSD Name: disk1s1
          Content: EFI
          Volume UUID: 0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
        disk1s2:
          Capacity: 4 TB (4 000 577 273 856 bytes)
          BSD Name: disk1s2


-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HD1-IMAC27              4.0 TB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk2
```

Below is the result from the two commands issued in OS High Sierra  after successful creation of a Fusion drive formatted in HFS+ and with one partition of the HD.
Yves:Imac-27- ~ yves$ system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
Hardware:

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name: iMac
  Model Identifier: iMac15,1
  Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 4 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Memory: 32 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 235.0.0.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 2.23f11
  Serial Number (system): C02NLC33FY14
  Hardware UUID: 7791AAC4-ED40-53C8-AA90-41C48B10DD89
```

Imac-27-Yves:~ yves$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS HD2-27                  2.0 TB     disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
4:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            2.0 TB     disk0s4
5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (internal):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         512.1 GB   disk1
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            511.8 GB   disk1s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +2.5 TB     disk2
Logical Volume on disk1s2, disk0s4
582B2901-BB86-47DC-857E-14E742AED9F9
Unencrypted Fusion Drive

Comment: SSDs don't become invisible to the system in any way.  All those "extra" drives are [RAM disks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399778/119271) needed for the install.  That said...let's slow down some.  I think your going into this without a clear picture of what you have in your possesion and how recovery works - that can cause major mistakes.  First, let's figure out what you have and from the looks of everything, you have an iMac with a 4TB disk drive.

Comment: We also need to know what iMac you specifically have.  Please issue the command:  `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Identifier` and post that info to the original question (not comments).  Also with `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType`  this will tell us what drives are installed.

Comment: @allan After additional experiments, I have edited my question. I can confirm now that when booted from OS High Sierra and above, the SSD is visible, can be partitioned, formatted, can be used either alone or in combination in a fusion drive formatted in HFS+, (and probably other formatting options, not tried) but as soon as I boot from Sierra, the SSD is gone, and even the size of the Fusion drive previously created in High Sierra appears to shrink, excluding the additional capacity previously provided by the SSD.

Comment: You need to provide the *full output* of the commands, not just the first few lines.  Now, Sierra is not compatible with APFS so you won't be able to mount those volumes, but you will be able to see attached hardware.  Hardware doesn't disappear under Sierra.  Additionally, keeping "Sierra" because it's compatible with older machines" makes no sense.  How are you defining this "incompatibility" with older machines?

Comment: What specific Mac do you have?  The 15,1 can be a late 2014 to mid-2015 5K iMac.  Please, boot into recovery (`Cmd-R`) then run the commands I provided so we can get a clear picture of what's installed on your iMac.  There's no need for all this "experimentation" at this time.

Comment: The Mac is a Imac retina 5K, 27", late 2004. The 4To HDD and the 512 Gb SSD have been changed by the previous owner. Again switching to OS10.13.6 (or more modern OS) has eliminated all previous  concerns and everything appears now normal.The SSD became visible, could be used for a fusion drive just formatted in HFS+. In recovery mode the commend does not work. I have edited mu question to add the results of the command issued from a fusion drive with High Sierra.

Comment: That doesn't make sense because the 27" Late 2014 iMac came with either a 128, 256, 512, or 1TB SSD and a 3TB HDD.  There was no 4TB option.  You've "stumbled" to your solution by downgrading to 10.13, but there is ***nothing*** that makes an SSD invisible, so you haven't really found a solution to fixing your problem.  That and you're on an obsolete version of macOS.  What this means is when you need to upgrade, you'll be back at square 1.  I belive the problem is in Catalina, it doesn't use "Fusion drives" anymore.  It's called logical volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not exactly identified the source of the problem, but after upgrading to High Sierra (OSX 10.13.6), everything went back to normal behavior. I could see the SSD again, format it, and combine it with the HD into a new fusion drive formatted in HFS+, as was the original disk setup of the computer.

Imac-27-Yves:~ yves$ diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         512.1 GB   disk0

1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1

2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            511.8 GB   disk0s2

3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk1

1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1

2:                  Apple_HFS HD2-27                  2.0 TB     disk1s2

3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3

4:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            2.0 TB     disk1s4

5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +2.5 TB     disk2

```
                             Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s4

                             582B2901-BB86-47DC-857E-14E742AED9F9
                             Unencrypted Fusion Drive
```